# Shape On Animation Path Is Wobbly And Shape Not Facing The Right Direction

Tags: animation

I have made an animation of a shape following a path 100 frames. The shape when following the path, doesnt seem to be too smooth, its a little bit wobbly from side to side. Also is there a way to see keyframes in the timeline although it's an animation path?

Also the face of the cube is not facing the right direction when turning along the path.

Thank you.

[image]

https://streamable.com/mmq44f

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the cube is not animated, the wobbling should be only due to realtime viewport delays, but a true render should be fine.

When you parent or constraint a follow path function, Blender creates a modifier inside the graph editor, generating a straight infinite line. You can delete the modifier and add manual keyframes on the path animation properies tab, knowing that the number of frames (100 in my example) is the value needed to complete the curve, and the evaluation time is the value of the keyframe (so that 50 will mean half path, 33 one third, and so on).

[image]

Comment: Thank you Josh! Worked well.

Answer (score 1):

For this I would create a cube, a bezier circle and an empty. All at the world origin. Scale the circle up to the size you'd like then select your cube. Add a Follow path constraint (target the bezier curve) and a track to constraint (target the empty). By keyframing the offset in the follow path constraint your box should orbit the circle and face inwards always.

The easiest way to manipulate moments on its journey between two keyframes is to open the graph editor Shift + F6. From there you can fine tune it's movements. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi James, I also just found this guys tutorial super helpful, shows you ways. One which is the one you mentioned I believe.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HsOSDYTsG7o&ab_channel=blenderBinge